# Data cleaning before, during or after data ingestion?

Tags: python, postgresql, architecture

I am building a self-contained data analytics project in Python. As the project needs to be scalable it requires a fairly solid pipeline of data processing and analytics.

So far I'm planning to use Singer (https://www.singer.io/) to ingest the data from multiple sources, with a PostgreSQL target.

The pipeline currently looks a bit like this:
data sources --> ingest --> store in postgreSQL DB --> data processing layer --> analytics environment.

I have already written Pandas code to clean data in the data processing layer - but I'm not sure if cleaning data as it is being pulled from the database into the analytics environment is the best practice. Especially as the data processing will then be repeated each time the data is pulled. Should I process the data in the ingestion layer? How would I do that with a Singer pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always it depends.

### Cleaning data before ingest

#### Pros

- It lowers network traffic / data volume
- It requires less storage

#### Cons

- It requires extra steps from each datasource
- It is hard to orchestrate, monitor these

### Cleaning data during ingest

#### Pros

- Preliminary checks are located in a single place
- You are able to report metrics

  - ingested, dropped, ingested-dropped ratio, etc.
- This step could be orchestrated and monitored easier

#### Cons

- It is just a preliminary check

  - During data modelling you might need to do further cleaning
- The maintenance of these rules is a responsibility of the data pipeline engineer

### Cleaning data after ingest

#### Pros

- It can be used not just for preliminary checks

  - For example: deduplication, filter unwanted outliers, etc.
- Different cleansing steps can be defined on a data model basis

#### Cons

- It requires more storage
- Each data scientist has to implement his/her own cleansing steps

---

This is not an exhaustive list but I hope it shows how you should start thinking about this problem.

Comment: @J.James I'm glad to hear. Which one did you pick if it is not confidential?

Comment: I've gone for the cleaning after ingest, as your point about different cleansing steps being defined for different models reminded me of just how different the processing of training data will likely be for each project. Though I may include some basic cleaning such as field name changes etc. pre-ingest. Thanks again Peter!